# Regex character find replace

Tags: php, regex

i am new to regex in PHP, and had a question

What i am trying to do (in PHP):

1. Find whether a string contains special characters or non-alphabets in a name (e.g. if term contains `-`, `*`, `.`, `&`, etc)
2. If string contains special characters - find and replace it using `str_replace`. Sample strings include 'e*trade', 'e-trade', 'Barnes&Noble', etc.

Comment: What did you try already? (Hint: there is a "word character" which can be negated)

Comment: [`preg_replace()`](http://us1.php.net/preg_replace)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Replace Symbols only

```
<?php
$regex = "/[-*.&]/";
$subject = "Barnes&Noble";
$replacement = "-";
$result = preg_replace($regex, $replacement, $subject);
echo $result;
```

Output:

> Barnes-Noble

---

### Replace all parts of the string if it matches Symbols:

```
<?php
$regex = "/(.*)([-*.&])(.*)/";
$subject = "Barnes&Noble";
$replacement = "$1 is not so $3";
$result = preg_replace($regex, $replacement, $subject);
echo $result;
```

Output:

> Barnes is not so Noble

---

http://ideone.com/ByXagy